# Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created a project in Visual Studio 2015  but after copy 
 and run on other computer it gives me below error

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)

Please give me suggestion how to fix it

Comment: Have you added a reference to your project?

Comment: run nuget restore... Alternatively make sure the reference is there and does not have a yellow mark next to it

Comment: no, there is no extra reference in the project and there is no yellow mark on any reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to fix this,

1. clean the project
2. run nuget restore
3. rebuild the project

If this does not work, try deleting the reference and adding it again by doing the following:

1. remove the reference if it is there.
2. go to the package.json and remove the EntityFramework line.
3. Go to Nuget package manager and reinstall the reference to your project.